How to Dynamically Center Elements in a Column with pdfMake?
I'm generating a PDF using pdfMake, and I'm having trouble dynamically centering elements within a column on the page. Specifically, I want to center an image and some text within a column, but the text content can change and might wrap to multiple lines, so I need the centering to adjust accordingly.
Below is the code I'm currently using:
const fs = require('fs');
const pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake');
const vfsFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts');
const sharp = require('sharp');

const inputImagePath = './photos/profil.png';
const outputImagePath = './photos/profil_circle.png';

sharp(inputImagePath)
  .metadata()
  .then(({ width, height }) => {
    const diameter = Math.min(width, height);

    return sharp(inputImagePath)
      .resize(diameter, diameter)
      .composite([{
        input: Buffer.from(
          `<svg><circle cx="${diameter / 2}" cy="${diameter / 2}" r="${diameter / 2}" fill="white"/></svg>`
        ),
        blend: 'dest-in'
      }])
      .png()
      .toFile(outputImagePath);
  })
  .then(() => {
    const photoBase64 = fs.readFileSync(outputImagePath, { encoding: 'base64' });

    const publicSansLight = fs.readFileSync('./fonts/PublicSans/PublicSans-Light.ttf', { encoding: 'base64' });
    const publicSansLightItalic = fs.readFileSync('./fonts/PublicSans/PublicSans-LightItalic.ttf', { encoding: 'base64' });
    const publicSansBold = fs.readFileSync('./fonts/PublicSans/PublicSans-Bold.ttf', { encoding: 'base64' });

    pdfMake.vfs = {
      ...vfsFonts.pdfMake.vfs,
      'PublicSans-Light.ttf': publicSansLight,
      'PublicSans-LightItalic.ttf': publicSansLightItalic,
      'PublicSans-Bold.ttf': publicSansBold,
      'profil_circle.png': photoBase64
    };

    const fonts = {
      PublicSans: {
        normal: 'PublicSans-Light.ttf',
        bold: 'PublicSans-Bold.ttf',
        italics: 'PublicSans-LightItalic.ttf',
        bolditalics: 'PublicSans-Bold.ttf'
      }
    };

    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8'));

    const docDefinition = {
      pageSize: 'A4',
      pageMargins: [20, 20, 20, 20],
      defaultStyle: {
        font: 'PublicSans'
      },
      content: [
        {
          columns: [
            {
              width: 'auto',
              image: 'profil_circle.png',
              fit: [125, 125],
              alignment: 'center'
            },
            {
              width: 400,
              stack: [
                {
                  text: `${data.firstname} ${data.lastname}`,
                  style: 'headerTitle'
                },
                {
                  text: `${data.city}, ${data.country}`,
                  style: 'header',
                  wordBreak: 'break-all'
                },
                {
                  text: data.tel,
                  style: 'header',
                  wordBreak: 'break-all'
                },
                {
                  text: data.email,
                  style: 'header',
                  wordBreak: 'break-all'
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          columnGap: 25,
        }
      ],
      styles: {
        headerTitle: {
          fontSize: 20,
          bold: true,
          color: '#37352F'
        },
        header: {
          fontSize: 14,
          color: '#747370'
        }
      }
    };

    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition, undefined, fonts).getBuffer(buffer => {
      fs.writeFileSync('CV.pdf', buffer);
      fs.unlinkSync(outputImagePath);
      console.log('CV created and circular image deleted.');
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  });

The issue I'm facing is that the elements in the left column (the circular image) and the right column (the text stack) are not vertically centered as expected. I've tried using alignment: 'center' within the columns object, but it doesn't seem to be working. Additionally, since the text content can change and wrap to multiple lines, I need the centering to adjust dynamically.
What am I missing? How can I properly center these elements within their respective columns, even when the text might cause a line break? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
